# Why do we need to normalise states in quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, s-matrix-theory, quantum-states, normalization

In QM its obvious that we need to normalise quantum states since their inner product  squared represents a probability. This normalization leads to physical states in QM being represented by 'rays' of vectors in the Hilbert space (i.e. with an arbitrary overall phase)

However in QFT, the inner product of the states no longer has this probability meaning, so why do we need to normalise states (e.g. choosing to normalise $|p\rangle = \sqrt{2 E_p} a_p^\dagger |\Omega\rangle$).

What would break if we did not normalise the states? Also what would be wrong with a state $k | p \rangle$ representing a different physical state to $| p \rangle$?

Is it just so that the inner product $\langle q | p \rangle$ is well-defined, even if it no longer represents probability amplitude?

Comment: *"However in QFT, the inner product of the states no longer has this probability meaning,"* - why do you say this? Of course the inner product is still a probability amplitude, QFT is still quantum mechanics!

Comment: I'm obviously confused about something. If $\langle q| p \rangle = (2\pi)^3 2 E_p \delta(p-q)$ then how exactly is this a probability amplitude? My point in the question was that the probability is not as simple as this value squred.

Comment: Well, that's because $\lvert q\rangle$ and $\lvert p\rangle$ aren't really nice properly normalizable states - but neither are they in ordinary QM, you have $\langle x\vert x'\rangle = \delta(x-x')$, there, too!

Comment: Ah true! Is there really no new issue at all then? Is my solution just that in general for normalizable states, $|\langle \psi_1 | \psi_2 \rangle|^2$  is still the probability in QFT. It's just (as in QM), for non-normalizable states (like momentum eigenstates) we have the freedom to choose whatever normalization is convenient since they aren't normalizable anyway?

Comment: One is always using a very well-defined normalization process in these continuous spectrum problems, of which QFT scattering is just one example. The apparent freedom/arbitrariness of your choice of normalization is an illusion - it is only because one normalizes against delta functions in the continuous spectrum that we can choose different factors in the intermediate steps, but at the end of the day that always has to be accounted for when one sets up e.g. a cross section or decay rate etc...

Comment: There are plenty of new issues in QFT, but normalization of states is not one of them.

Comment: Amazing thanks I think this is the answer

Comment: It just looks new because very few QM books discuss normalization in the continuous spectrum properly, and even fewer do it in a way that they then apply that QM thinking to QFT directly. Landau explains it all in a unified manner.

Comment: @bolbteppa thanks. So most books don't explain it because it is too difficult (for the reader) , but of course Landau treats it for the same reason :)

Comment: QFT is just quantum mechanics but with infinitely many degrees of freedom. States have to be normalized in QFT just like they have to be in QM. What makes you say otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QM and QFT are probabilistic (hence unitary) theories, and in each theory a given outcome has a specific probability in a given physical state.  One well-studied special case of QM is a $1$-particle system; but just because that's not how the states in QFT look, it doesn't mean we don't still have a notion of unitarity, which is all normalization demands. We can then recover probability distributions from suitably computed expectations, in much the same manner as in QM.

For example, the equivalent of $\langle m|\hat{H}|n\rangle$ becomes $\langle p|\hat{H}|q\rangle$; in both cases, complete knowledge of the matrix elements gives the probability distribution of the vacuum's classical Hamiltonian $H$ when observed. (All the footnotes and asterisks about normal ordering, how we make a field theory's Hamiltonian finite over $\Bbb R^3$ and so on are left to the reader.)